# How to Validate the value of text field after pasting some text in a text field regex in extjs?

Tags: extjs

In my application a text field is there where only regex: /[A-Z0-9_]/ should be allowed.
its working fine when we enter values from key board with the code i pasted below.
Problem is when i **paste** some value other than regex is being accepted using ctrl+v and rightclick paste.
NoteI disabled right click and ctrl+v events on key down which is not good solution for my problem please help me in solving this..
please tell me how to validate the value of text field after pasting some text .

```
          Mycode: { 
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    flex: 1,
                    allowBlank: false,
                    maskRe: /[A-Z0-9_]/,
                    maxLength: 50,
                    regex: /[A-Z0-9_]/,
                    ref: '../refField',
                    enableKeyEvents:true,
                    listeners: {
                        keydown: function(field, e){
                            if((e.getKey() ==86) && e.ctrlKey){
                                e.stopEvent();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Regards,
raj

Answer (score 3):

You could try call validate method on the keyup event, as suggested here:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?27147-Trying-to-get-extjs-to-react-to-text-changing-on-a-text-field

But as they say, it wont guarantee that this will work in all browsers. In my view 100% solution is to call validate() on field in the **blur** event.

something like:

```
combo.on('blur', funciton(field){
    !if(field.isValid()){
         //do what you need, for example clean the value in the field
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi,My regex is regex: /[A-Z0-9_]/,if i enter 0-9 numbers and paste anything other than the regex its accepting.So can you please tell how to check the value of a text field on paste and validate accordingly and restrict the characters a-z on paste.
please its emergency.

Raj

Comment: Its accepting any value after and before the regex value by pasting using ctrl + v and mouse right click paste.